# WPF RelayCommand not firing on button click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm-light

I'm inexperienced with both WPF and MVVM so i'm most likeley missing something but when I click my button the command isn't firing. I also have some menu controls on my page that i've setup the exact same way and when I click those, their commands work as expected.

I've tried attaching a click event handler to make sure the button is definitely being clicked which it is. I've also tried attaching a different command that works on my menu control which didn't work on the button.

```xml
<Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Add Note" 
                                        Command="{Binding InsertNoteCommand}"/>
```

```cs
public ICommand InsertNoteCommand { get; }

public MainViewModel()
{
    InsertNoteCommand = new RelayCommand(InsertNote);
}

private void InsertNote()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Note Inserted!");
}
```

I should also mention that i'm using MVVM Light

Comment: Looks like the `DataContext` is not the `MainViewModel`. Do you get binding errors in the output? Make sure the `Button` has the proper `DataContext` set, so that the binding can resolve.

Comment: Datacontext is set using some code from MVVM light. I've tried setting the datacontext directly and I get the same result. Also, my page has data bindings and the menu that work the way its set up now.

Comment: Have you checked the output window for error messages? Go to the menu and select "Debug/Options/Debugging/Output Window/WPF Trace Settings" and set the 'Data Binding' trace level to 'All' or at least 'Warning'. Now run in debug mode and check the output in the Output Window. It will show failing bindings e.g. property _x_ not found on binding source _y_.

Comment: Additionally localize the `Button` with the Live Visual Tree Explorer. Go to "Debug/Windows/Live Visual Tree". After you selected the `Button` element you can view its actual property values in the Live Property Explorer ("Debug/Windows/Live Property Explorer"). Check if the `DataContext` is set to the `MainViewModel`.

Comment: Hello, a good way to get better help sooner is to show us what you have tried and exactly where you are stuck. Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), often known as a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

The debugging information is very useful to know but in the end I solved the problem by pointing the binding to the data context.

```
<Button x:Name="AddNewNoteBtn" Grid.Row="1" Content="Add Note" 
                                        Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.InsertNoteCommand,  ElementName=_window}"/>
```

If anybody has comments on how I can improve this I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to use elementname at all? Datacontext is marked as inherits so you set the datacontext of the window and a button in that window has the same datacontext. You should be able to just do Binding InsertNoteCommand unless you have set the button or a parent of it to some other datacontext or your button is not in the visual tree of the window.

Comment: It is inside a DataTemplate inside Window.Resources so perhaps that prevents it from being inside the visual tree? @Andy